# Logstash not writing data from external file to elasticsearch

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a sample text file named `testfile.txt` containing simple "Hi". I want this data to get indexed on `ElasticSearch`. I run the following command on `logstash`:

```
bin/logstash -f logstash-test.conf
```

Conf File content is below:

```
input{
    file
        {
            path=> "/home/abhinav/ELK/logstash/testfile.txt"
            type => "test"
            start_position => "beginning"
        }
     }
output{
     elasticsearch { host => localhost 
             index => "test_index"
               }
     stdout { codec => rubydebug } 
      }
```

The ElasticSearch Log shows the follwing error:

> [2015-05-04 14:52:23,082][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Argo]
>   added
>   {[logstash-abhinav-HP-15-Notebook-PC-10919-4006][CPk1djqFRnO-j-DlUMJIzg][abhinav-HP-15-Notebook-PC][inet[/192.168.1.2:9301]]{client=true,
>   data=false},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(join from
>   node[[logstash-abhinav-HP-15-Notebook-PC-10919-4006][CPk1djqFRnO-j-DlUMJIzg][abhinav-HP-15-Notebook-PC][inet[/192.168.1.2:9301]]{client=true,
>   data=false}])

I tried following things:

Tried with simple std input(stdin) to ES n stdout . It worked.

Comment: So, you solved your own problem? If so, please post the solution as an answer.

Comment: Not Yet ! I'll post answer in comments once I find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the same file repeatedly to test with, you are running into the "sincedb" problem -- see [How to force Logstash to reparse a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546900/how-to-force-logstash-to-reparse-a-file)

You need to add `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"` to your file input.  Generally this is not needed in a production scenario, but it is when testing.

Comment: Thanks ! You told me the right concept. Though this thing , adding sincedb path , didn't work, but I got things Right. I reinstalled E L K , then for tried running different conf files and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution to my problem and also found things we can check, if logstash & ES not working/communicating properly. :

- Make sure ES & Logstash are properly installed
- Versions installed are compatible with each other
- Even while testing, try making different Logstash conf file for different test case, as suggested by Mr. Alcanzar in above comment.

You can also refer to below links , for help regarding this issue :

[Cannot load index to elasticsearch from external file, using logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272915/cannot-load-index-to-elasticsearch-from-external-file-using-logstash)

https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1800